# Responsys: Create a tracked link with dynamic path

Tags: crm, responsys

I am looking to create a dynamic/tracked link from a supplementary tabled based on product ID.

The URL format is:

```
https: // site.com/product/{$id}
```

Using the `${clickthrough('my_products',table.id)}` method hasn't worked.  The resulting URL, while tracked doesn't transform the ID parameter and results in a broken link.

Would like to know, what the clickthrough function should be and what to include in the link table.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL format needs to be updated to:

> https : //site.com/product/**${id}**

Then you need to add the parameter table.id to pass through to id (RI will recognize id as table.id most of the time, so this is unnecessary unless you're coding the URL in a <#data> loop where the field is aliased):

> ${clickthrough('my_products', 'id=' + table.id)}

Or you could just change ${id} to ${table.id} to call the field in directly so you don't have to code the parameter in the clickthrough:

> https : //site.com/product/**${table.id}**
>
> ${clickthrough('my_products')}